# How to check if a string is equal to a string literal

Tags: c++, string, compare, string-literals

I wanted to compare a string to a string literal; something like this:

```
if (string == "add")
```

Do I have to declare `"add"` as a string or is it possible to compare in a similar way?

Comment: What is the type of `string`? Is it a C++ `std::string` object, or simply a `const char*`?

Comment: @e.James awnser is good. Also worth mentioning that a string or char sequence literal should be enclosed with `"` (double quotes), single quotes are for single char literals.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

In C++ the `std::string` class implements the [comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp), so you can perform the comparison using `==` just as you would expect:

```
if (string == "add") { ... }
```

When used properly, [operator overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading) is an excellent C++ feature.

Comment: Well now I'm *really* confused. If `string` is a `std::string` object, this will work, but then `strcmp()` would *not* have worked. Which is it? I'm dying to know! `:)`

Comment: But it should be noted, that the comparison will yield a different result if "string" is `char*` !

Comment: e.James: if "string" is std::string, then `if( strcmp(string.c_str(),"add")==0 ) {...}` would work.

Comment: @frunsi: Yes, but that would be *really* unnecessary. I was referring to Anon's comment in Christopher Armstrong's answer (where he says that `if (strcmp(string, "add") == 0) { ... }` worked.

Comment: @frunsi: I am worried that `string` *is* a `char*`, in which case this is the wrong answer. I was hoping Anon would clarify that.

Comment: What if `string` is a `char*` ? What should I do?

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `strcmp`.

```
if (strcmp(string,"add") == 0){
    print("success!");
}
```

Comment: Note: `strcmp()` is a C function which takes pointers to `const char*` as its arguments. It works in this case because the `std::string` object is converted back into a `const char*`, but this is *not* the best way to do things in C++

Comment: @e.James: No, `std::string` does not implicitly convert to `const char*`, you need to call `s.c_str()` for that.  But according to the question "without defining either one as a string", `string` isn't a `std::string` to begin with.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Ah, yes you are right about the down-conversion. My mistake.

Comment: In C code you should prefer strncmp() over strcmp(), which is safer solution.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option A - use `std::string`

`std::string` has an operator overload that allows you to compare it to another string.

```cpp
std::string string = "add";
if (string == "add") // true
```

#### Option B - use `std::string_view`<sup>(C++17)</sup>

If one of the operands isn't already a `std::string` or `std::string_view`, you can wrap either operand in a `std::string_view`. This is very cheap, and doesn't require any dynamic memory allocations.

```cpp
#include <string_view>
// ...

if (std::string_view(string) == "add")
// or
if (string == std::string_view("add"))
// or
using namespace std::string_literals;
if (string == "add"sv)
```

#### Option C - use `strcmp`<sup>(compatible with C)</sup>

If neither of those options is available, or you ned to write code that works in both C and C++:

```cpp
#include <string.h>
// ...

const char* string = "add";
if (strcmp(string, "add") == 0) // true
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `strcmp()`:

```
/* strcmp example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char szKey[] = "apple";
  char szInput[80];
  do {
     printf ("Guess my favourite fruit? ");
     gets (szInput);
  } while (strcmp (szKey,szInput) != 0);
  puts ("Correct answer!");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will work (because C++ is backwards-compatible with C) but it is *not* the best way to do things in C++

Comment: This also has a buffer overflow issue, there is no length checking on szInput

Answer (score -1):

We use the following set of instructions in the C++ computer language.

**Objective:** verify if the value inside `std::string` container is equal to "add":

```
if (sString.compare(“add”) == 0) { //if equal
    // Execute
}
```