# cannot understand the if command

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm trying to write a program, which shows a custom message in the console when I type `load`. But I can't seem to get it to work. :/

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int commands();
    string text;
    cout << "Write your registered e-mail to continue...\n";
    cin >> text;

    string input;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Welcome " << text << endl;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "www.steamcommunity.com/id/thetraderdazz> ";
    cin >> input;
    if (input = load);
    cout << "loading...";

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

It also gives me the following error:

> identifier "load" is undefined.

Comment: You seem to have quite a few misunderstandings about C++. You should take a step back and systematically learn the language from a  good book.

Comment: Agree with comment above. Here's some help with your particular problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222583/how-to-compare-strings

Comment: I agree with all the comments above, but first, you should be using the strcmp function instead of `=` (which does assignment, I think you meant `==`) and you have to make `load` a string, so: `"load"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (input = load);
```

There are three mistakes with this line. The first is that you used the assignment operator `=` instead of comparison operator `==`. The former assigns, the latter compares.

The second mistake is that you placed a semicolon after the parenthesis, indicating an empty body. Your compiler should have given you a warning about this.

Finally, there is no variable `load`. You mean to compare to string literal `"load"`.

Fix to

```
if (input == "load")
    cout << "loading...\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably intended the following

```
if (input == "load") {
 cout << "loading...";
}
```