# C++ Server Program Print While Loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, boolean-logic

I am creating a server/client socket program and am in the process of making a method to print server input.

Here's my code:

```
void *admin_handler (void *ptr) {
    char strBuf [100000];
    const char strExit [20] = "Server: terminated.";

    while(1) {
        scanf ("%s", strBuf);
        int i;
        for (i=0; i < nClient; i++){
            if (strBuf == "Exit"){
                write (nFDList [i], strExit, strlen (strExit) + 1);
            }
            else {
                write (nFDList [i], strBuf, strlen (strBuf) + 1);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

When I execute, though, even when I type in "Exit", it still executes the else statement. How can I modify the if statement to execute when I type "Exit"?

Comment: Try strcmp instead of the `==` comparison

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222583/how-to-compare-strings)

Comment: Thanks @CannedMoose that solved it!

Comment: In addition to the above advice, tossing 100,000 bytes onto the stack (or whatever is used to provide Automatic storage) can push you dangerously close to a stack overflow. Consider using `cin` and `std::string` instead if you need to take inputs this large. `std::string` sizes itself to fit and is allocated from Dynamic storage (usually larger than Automatic storage by several orders of magnitude).

Comment: Don't see C++ there.

Comment: @S.M. Just because you don't like the code doesn't mean it's not C++.

Comment: @S.M. You are looking at a common subset (hi Lightness ;-) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to compare strings in **C** is using `strcmp()` (or `strncmp()` if one is interested in safety with unknown strings).

The equality operator `==` compares the operands directly, after they "decay" to pointers; the pointers do not change and are of course different. `strcmp()`, by contrast, inspects the contents of the *memory pointed to,* which may be equal.

As an aside, the same issue exists in **Java:** `==` checks whether both sides are the same *objects*, similar to the C equivalent, while `.equals()` inspects the object *contents*, similar to `strcmp()`.

**C#**, by  contrast, overloaded `==` for strings so that it would indeed look at the contents, which makes a lot of sense for a language where operator overloading is possible (which C is not): Testing the identity of the objects is almost never desired and, as we see, is a common source of error.

Comment: Sorry, I kind of hijacked your answer ;-). I only wanted to provide some context and got carried away. But it is useful information, even if it is redundant on SO.